# Firebase transaction()-like functionality when adding to a list?

Tags: firebase

This is a rather involved question, but I'll try to explain it as simply & concisely as I can...

I am using Firebase to build a multi-user, web-based game. I am keeping a list of every round in the game. At the end of a round, every user is presented with a "Start" button that they click when they are ready to begin the next round. The round begins when at least 50% of users have clicked "Start".

I have a Firebase reference `gameRef` for the game, a reference `roundListRef` that represents the list of rounds, and a reference `roundRef` that represents the current round.

I have attached a `child_added` callback to `roundListRef` so that when a new round is added, it becomes everyone's current round:

```
roundListRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildName) {
    roundRef = childSnapshot.ref();
});
```

I can track `newRoundVotes` and `activePlayers`, and calculate 50% easily from there. If 50% is reached, a new round is added, which triggers everyone's `child_added` event and the new round will begin from there...

```
gameRef.child('newRoundVotes').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    var newRoundVotes = snapshot.val();

    gameRef.child('activePlayers').once('value', function(snapshot) {
        var activePlayers = snapshot.val();

        if (newDriveVotes / activePlayers >= 0.5)
            addNewRound();
    });
});
```

My questions is, how do I ensure that only one new round is added, and that everyone is on the same round?

For example, say there are 10 players and 4 have already voted to start the next round. If the 6th player votes before his `child_added` event is triggered from the 5th player, then a round will also be added for the 6th player.

The problem is similar to `.set()` vs `.transaction()`, but no quite the same (from my understanding).

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can likely solve this with a transaction if the round names are known ahead of time.  E.g. if you just use /round/0, /round/1, /round/2, etc.

Then you could have some code like:

```
function addNewRound() {
    var currentRound = Number(roundRef.name());
    var nextRound = currentRound + 1;

    // Use a transaction to try to create the next round.
    roundRefList.child(nextRound).transaction(function(newRoundValue) {
        if (newRoundValue == null) {
            // create new round.
            return { /* whatever should be stored for the round. */ };
        } else {
            // somebody else already created it.  Do nothing.
        }
    });
}
```

Does this work for your scenario?

Comment: Ha! That's so much simpler. I hadn't even considered that you could just use `transaction` on a child that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Yes it does - great idea! I've been using push() just because it was a list and had not even thought of doing anything like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your thinking slightly and use a round counter as a place to track concurrency.

```
currentRound = 0;
currentRoundRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
   currentRound = snapshot.val();
   roundRef = roundListRef.child(currentRound);
});

function addNewRound() {
    currentRoundRef.transaction( function(current_value) {
       if( current_value !== currentRound ) {
          // the round timer has been updated by someone else
          return;
       }
       else {
          return currentRound + 1;
       }
    }, function(success) {
       // called after our transaction succeeds or fails
       if( success ) {
          roundListRef.child(currentRound+1).set(...);
       }
    });
}
```